# Remove email validation on login form using Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, validation, devise, ldap

SOLVED!

Sorry for bothering ya all, I solved it myself after some more code digging :)

The problem was in the views/devise/sessions/new.html.erb

The field I tried to use for UID was in fact of type f.email_field. Changed it to f.text_field and the email validation went away :)

Leaving this post and hopes it helps someone else.

---

Im the new guy on the block I guess. I've been following the excellent tutorial [Device with LDAP for Authentication in Rails 3](http://wiki.phys.ethz.ch/readme/devise_with_ldap_for_authentication_in_rails_3). My goal is to authenticated against an eDir server. What I've tried to customise is exchanging the :email cridential and use Novells UID instead. The problem arises as I try to login on the users/log_in page. Validation check on username(email) says I dont got a valid emailaddress(ofcouse I dont, I try to use my UID). Can I turn this of(validation) somehow. I tried to edit the regexp in config/initializers/devise.rb without any success.

If this has already been answered I appolagize, I really have tried to find the answer to this.